# how to get the same line through different <p> Tags

Tags: html, css, reactjs, paragraph

am trying to use this css property "text-decoration: line-through;" on two different

Tags and without breaking the line

```css
.pricereview {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.prixunit {
  color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.tnd {
  color: lightgrey;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricereview">
  <div class="price">
    <p class="prixunit">560</p>
    <p class="tnd">TND</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the result that I want:
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPMHJ.png)

Comment: You can't using `text-decoration`. Consider using a pseudo-element on the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) tags and wrapping them in another element. Use a pseudo-element on the wrapper to make your "linebreak" span multiple elements of different font sizes and line heights without breaking.

```css
.price {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.price::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}

.prixunit {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.tnd {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 26px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p class="price">
  <span class="prixunit">560</span>
  <span class="tnd">TND</span>
</p>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but the font sizes are not the same

Comment: You can add classes to the `<span>`s and style them as you'd like. The linebreak will break on font-size change, though. I'd suggest using a pseudo-element to create a consistent break.

Comment: when he sets the two span tags with different font sizes, the line breaks and each span will have it's own line.

Comment: @AlaBenAicha Ah, my mistake. Updated my answer with a working solution.

Answer (score -1):

You cant do that with a p tag, cause its a block-level element
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

And it seems that in your case you want to make a line that is not cutting exactly in the middle of the word. If its your case, text-decoration: line-through dont will help you.